# enum confusion if the code is running correct

Tags: java, enums

why default and enum both printed. getting default and other unassigned value also... Hi everyone, I have the cars enum, when I run this code I get both honda and no car , can sombody tell?

```
public enum Cars{Audi, honda, ferrari};
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     
     Cars myCars = Cars.ferrari;
      switch (myCars ) {
      case Audi:
       System.out.print("audi");
      
      default:    
        System.out.print("no car");

      case honda:
        System.out.print("honda");
      }
```

Comment: You need to use `break` between cases.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put in `break` statements in each of your cases. Your default case should also be at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't break out of your switch.  So it hits Default and then falls through to Honda.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a break statement after each case

Answer (score 0):

Dude.. switch cases continue to fall to next case unless you use a break statement like **waterfall approach**.Also,its a good programming practice to keep your default statement at the very last

```
Cars myCars = Cars.ferrari;
  switch (myCars ) {
  case Audi:
  System.out.print("audi");
  break;

  case honda:
  System.out.print("honda");
  break;

  default:
  System.out.print("no car");     
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

## *Normal* Switch

As already answered (some time ago), you must add a `break` at the end of each Switch Group:

```java
switch (myCars) {
    case Audi:
        System.out.print("audi");
        break;  // << needed, otherwise the code continues with next group
    default:
        // ...
```

## Switch Rules ¹

Since Java 14 there are Switch Rules, which don't require a `break`:

```java
switch (myCars) {
    case Audi -> System.out.print("audi");
    default -> System.out.print("no car");  // I would move that to the end!
    case honda -> System.out.print("honda");
}
```

## Switch Expression ¹

Also since Java 14, we got Switch Expressions:

```java
System.out.println( switch (myCars) {
    case Audi -> "audi";
    default -> "no car";  // I would move that to the end!
    case honda -> "honda";
    } );
```

A switch Expression *can* be used with the *usual* switch blocks, the resulting value is given by the new `yield` statement:

```java
System.out.println( switch (myCars) {
        case Audi: yield "audi";
        default: yield "no car";  // I would move that to the end!
        case honda: { additionalMethod(); yield "honda"; } // just a block
    } );
```

---

### NULL ²

Released in Java 21: handling of `null` case in switch statements and switch expressions, otherwise these would throw a `NullPointerException`:

```java
switch (myCars) {
    case Audi -> System.out.print("audi");
    case honda -> System.out.print("honda");
    case null -> System.out.println("no car");
    default -> System.out.print("I don't know that car");
}
```

Similar with the other kind of switch blocks. Here it is important that `null` comes before `default`!

---

<sub>**1** [JEP 361: Switch Expressions](https://openjdk.org/jeps/361)</sub>

<sup>**2** [JEP 441: Pattern Matching for switch](https://openjdk.org/jeps/441)</sup>